# concurrent modification exception while iterating list map string object and edit key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, iterator, concurrentmodification

I'm putting in a `List<Map<String, Object>>` the result of a query along with the column names. Sometimes column names are like `TableAlias.ColumnName`, in that case I want to change it to just `ColumnName` and remove `TableAlias.` for that I have below code:

```
queryResult = namedParameterJdbcTemplateHive.queryForList(query, paramSource);

for (Map<String, Object> map : queryResult) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {            
        String[] keyData = entry.getKey().split("\\.");
        if (keyData.length > 0) {
            Object obj = map.remove(entry.getKey());
            map.put(keyData[1], obj);
        }                   
    }
}
```

That is giving me `concurrent modification exception` so I was trying with an iterator like below:

```
for (Map<String, Object> map : queryResult) {
    for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
        String[] keyData = entry.getKey().split("\\.");
        if (keyData.length > 0) {
            it.remove();                        
        }
    }
}
```

But not sure how to add the item back with the new key.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: just a side note: if you are removing the table alias, you are open for conflicts! Just imagine the case of `tablename.id` and `tablename2.id`. If you remove the table name, you will overwrite one id value with another id value without realizing it in the end. Highly dangerous imho

Comment: Or in short: put the results into a new map. Then, you can skip the removal of the key from the old map and just continue using the new map afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would iterate over the original map and fill another map with the updated keys.

```java
queryResult = namedParameterJdbcTemplateHive.queryForList(query, paramSource);

Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   String[] keyData = entry.getKey().split("\\.");
   if (keyData.length > 1) {
       newMap.put(keyData[1], entry.getValue());
   } else {
       newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

Comment: I just saw that you have a list of maps, you might need to adapt by adding the newMap to a new List afterwards...

Comment: you are absolutely right about your comment above, I didn't think about having the same field name in different tables. Thanks for the response but I will keep the alias then :)

Comment: What’s strange, is the `keyData.length > 0` condition, followed by accessing `keyData[1]`. The condition will never be `false`, as splitting a string can’t yield zero elements, but when there’s no dot, the operation will produce an exception…

Comment: Alternatively, `for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: map.entrySet()) { newMap.put(entry.getKey().replaceFirst("(?s).*?\\.([^.]*).*", "$1"), entry.getValue()); }`…

Comment: I had a problem. Someone told me to use regex. Now I have two problems...